# How to do complex conditionals or regex in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm having an interesting challenge and can't figure out how to go about solving it. I'm pulling a list of subscribers from my mailchimp and populating a members' page on my website with the data. One of the field in my sign up for says, "Website or LinkedIn profile url."

What I'd like to do is, check if they have provided a linkedin address, and if so drop their url in the linkedin member plugin, if not use the other data to create a simpler profile, name website, headline etc.

My problem is I can't say if data.websiteField.match(/linkedin/) within jade, so I either need to pass the data to some client side javascript which I'm having trouble with or do something else.

Here's a sample of data returned from mailchimp

```
[ // this first bit is just the fields
  [
    "email address",
    "first name",
    "last name",
    "role",
    "organization",
    "headline",
    "website",
    "areas of interest",
    "please email me about:",
    "member_rating",
    "optin_time",
    "optin_ip",
    "confirm_time",
    "confirm_ip",
    "latitude",
    "longitude",
    "gmtoff",
    "dstoff",
    "timezone",
    "cc",
    "region",
    "last_changed"
  ],
  [ // and here's the first user
    "woop@booomshakala.com", // haha, just hiding some data
    "Woop",
    "Shak",
    "Tester",
    "ShakaCo",
    "Whooooooper",
    "http://linkedin.com/in/costamichailidis", // hit me up sometime
    "Creativity, Innovation, Ideas and Science",
    "Job Placement, Internships, Recruitment &amp; Retention, Technology &amp; MOOCs, Measurement &amp; Evaluation, Documentation &amp; Dissemination",
    2,
    "2013-03-28 19:28:55",
    "173.52.122.111",
    "2013-03-28 19:29:12",
    "173.52.122.111",
    "40.7648000",
    "-73.7775000",
    "-5",
    "-4",
    "America/New_York", "US", "NY", "2013-03-28 19:29:12"
  ]
]
```

Any help would rock!

Also, I'm using express. Does express make locals available in client side javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Client Side Regex

Jade allows you execute arbitrary javascript using the `-` modifier at the start of the line

```
- if (profile.websiteField.match(/linkedin/)
    // render linkedin profile here
- else
    // render simple profile here
```

## Server Side Regex

I think it would be simpler to format the profile information server-side and set a `renderLinkedIn` boolean field to true or false

```
function displaySignUpPage(req, res) {
  var profile = formatMailChimpData()
  // profile now looks like
  // {
  //   "email address": "woop@booomshakala.com",
  //   "first name": "Noah",
  //   ...
  // }

  var linkedInRegex = /linkedin/;
  profile.renderLinkedIn = linkedInRegex.test(profile.website) // set renderLinkedIn to true or false
  // say your jade view is called signUpPage.jade
  var pageData = {
    title: 'Register',
    profile: profile
  }
  res.render('signUpPage', pageData)
}


function formatMailChimpData() {
  var mailChimpData = [
    [
      "email address",
      "first name",
      "last name",
      "role",
      "organization",
      "headline",
      "website"
      // other fields truncated
    ],
    [
      "woop@booomshakala.com", // haha, just hiding some data
      "Noah",
      "Isaacson",
      "Tester",
      "ShakaCo",
      "Whooooooper",
      "http://www.linkedin.com/pub/noah-isaacson/59/6a2/553"
    ]
  ]


  // mailChimp puts the keys as the first entry
  var mailChimpFields = mailChimpData[0]
  var mailChimpProfile = mailChimpData[1]
  // make profile into key-value pairs
  var keyValuePairs = mailChimpFields.map(function (field, index) {
    var profileValue = mailChimpProfile[index]
    var keyValuePair = [field, profileValue]
    return keyValuePair
   })
  var profile = keyValuePairs.reduce(function(prev, pair) {
    var key = pair[0]
    var value = pair[1]
    prev[key] = value
    return prev
  }, {})
  return profile
}
```

Comment: You Rock! I read right past this in the documentation. Thanks, Noah.

Comment: No problem. The code to convert the mailchimp data to profile objects should probably be wrapper up into a module at some point

Comment: I was thinking it's probably best to do it client side, as part of an load-as-you-scroll function. I figured if I tried to manipulate each subscriber on the server, that would hinder performance. Any thoughts?

Comment: The other way to go (if the data set was big enough), would be to do it as the data streams, but I'm no where near that experienced with streams.

Comment: I would guess that server-side would be more than fast enough. Benchmark it client-side vs server-side and see.

Comment: It's possible I will pull a couple thousand arrays from mailchimp per request. Isn't that a bit much?

Comment: hard telling not knowing. Only way to be sure is to try both